# How to print from GitHub

Tags: github, markdown, pretty-print

If I want to print a markdown file from GitHub as it appears on screen, for example:
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md

Then how can I accomplish that? What code do I need to change in the resulting github html page (that I save) such that the printout will honor the look & feel of the markdown?

So far the only clue I have is this one:
https://makandracards.com/makandra/4947-how-to-print-github-wiki-pages
But it is more of a utilitarian (non-programmatic) workaround which doesn't really work because the markdown interpreter in use isn't as forgiving as the one running on the GitHub websites so it fumbles.

Answer (score 74):

Here is [a bookmarklet](https://gist.github.com/davidcann/2d65fb189cdee31a6dcaa248f46afec3) that works for me:

1. Copy the contents of the bookmarklet Gist, reproduced below as a backup.
2. Create a new bookmark in the toolbar of your browser, give it a fitting name.
3. Put that one line of code in the URL field.

If you now go to a Markdown page on Github and click the bookmark it will reformat the page and change the CSS so that it looks the same as on screen when you print. It will also automaticaly trigger the printing dialog to pop up.

Bookmarklet contents:

```
javascript:document.body.appendChild(document.querySelector("#readme"));document.querySelector("header").remove();document.querySelector(".application-main").remove();document.querySelector("footer").remove();window.print();
```

Comment: I found this bookmarklet wasn't properly removing the Github header for logged in users, so I updated it [at an updated gist here](https://gist.github.com/4454331)

Comment: broken since new github design

Comment: Is there an uncompressed version of this file anywhere in case I want to try out some edits ? This is all compressed / encrypted code in the gist currently.

Comment: Answer has been updated with the latest version from @randomor

Comment: Yet another update, works with the Sep 2014 design:  https://gist.github.com/csoma/de71e151607940d6e523

Comment: It's a shame that this is so fragile. There really should be a separate tool to which one can feed just the MD file and from which flows printable HTML without the header/footer/sidebar/chrome stuff which these gists and bookmarklets all struggle to suppress. It'd be very cool if there were a tool which turns an MD into a PDF like gitprint.com claims (but fails) to do.

Comment: Updated version can be found here - https://gist.github.com/jczaplew/319856742c75acb257ce

Comment: Updated the answer with @jczaplew's version

Comment: This is where it's broken.

Comment: Made it work for github too: https://gist.github.com/reallistic/189c1fade597d6af8869d7d076351df2

Comment: Here's one for 2022: https://gist.github.com/davidcann/2d65fb189cdee31a6dcaa248f46afec3

Comment: @davidcann thanks for the new bookmarklet. I updated the answer to include and link to yours.

Answer (score 39):

Here's a super simple solution: Simply select all the text in the readme that you want to print, then print and choose "Only selected text".

This worked perfectly in Chrome (including images) and required no javascript or external sites or downloading or building software.

This is what I tested on: 
https://github.com/kroitor/gjk.c/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Nice! The option in Chrome is now called `More settings` -- `Selection only`. It supports the formatting and doesn't require additional software or downloading the markdown file.

Comment: When printing from Firefox, select the content you want to print, access the "Print" option from the "File" menu (or press `ctrl + p`), then select the "Selection" option.

Comment: This is the way. As of Chrome 107, just select the text, right click -> Print...

Answer (score 18):

Another option is [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/). After installing (it supports Windows, Linux and Mac OS), the command would be along the lines of
`pandoc file.md -f markdown --smart -s -o file.pdf`

Then print the resulting PDF file.

---

There is also this online converter, which produced the nicest output for me:
http://www.markdowntopdf.com/

Pandoc has an online demo as well.

**Update 2020**: on macOS Catalina this command worked for me:

```
brew install pandoc
brew install --cask basictex
pandoc README.md -f markdown+smart -s -o out.pdf --pdf-engine=/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex --pdf-engine=xelatex
```

Comment: Found this tool very effective https://www.markdowntopdf.com/

Comment: How to get original markdown from random public issue?
e.g. https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/650

Answer (score 14):

If you are a Mac-User, another great possibility is to use the "Reader"-Functionality in the Safari web browser.

Just open the markdown-File and click the "Reader"-Button in the top right-corner.

Then just print the page with the command "CMD + P".

Works like a charm.

Comment: This no longer seems to work on the latest iOS/Safari :(

Comment: Works well on macOS 10.14 Mojave, although I had filename positioned below my H1 (largest header) on the first line of a .md (markdown) file weirdly after printing a hardcopy to paper.

Answer (score 7):

I made a Chrome extension that does just this: [GitHub Markdown Printer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-markdown-printer/fehpdlpmcegfpbkgcnaleindodeegapk). It's a **one-click** solution for printing markdown files **exactly** how they appear on GitHub.

#### Steps:

1. Install the Chrome extension
2. Go to any page on GitHub/GitHub Enterprise with a markdown preview
3. Click the GMP icon to open the print dialog and either print or save as PDF

Check out the [repo](https://github.com/jerry1100/github-markdown-printer) for more info.

Comment: The extension reads and writes to all pages you visit. Not sure how secure it is

Comment: @VikramKhemlani That's a valid concern, but I assure you I'm not doing anything malicious. The read permission is required to see if 1) you are on github and 2) if there is a valid markdown preview. The write permission is required to add a custom stylesheet to remove the extra elements when printing.

The project is open-source and you can find the source code here: https://github.com/jerry1100/github-markdown-printer/tree/master/src. If you're still doubtful, you can open the network tab in your chrome devtools and find that I'm not sending any data anywhere.

Comment: @JerryWu There is a way to manually setup the extension to work only on gist.github.com and github.com pages when managing extensions in the browser and I'm pretty sure there is also a way to set defaults for those settings in your extension's code, right away. Anyways, kudos, your extension is better than marking and copying the page, because it will provide better styles, so much text can be printed on each page. I like this extension. Only problem I see is that it reserves pages for the comments on gist.github.com, so I have to specify the page start/end to not print a lot of empty pages.

Comment: @MartinBraun thanks for the feedback. When I was developing this, I was working at IBM and needed to match github.ibm.com. Since github.*.com isn't a valid match pattern, I went with my current approach. If you know of a less-invasive way, let me know and I'll try it out. Also, I fixed the issue with comments on gists, look out for v0.6 :)

Comment: Good news - as of v0.8, this extension no longer requires any permissions or site access, thanks to the new manifest v3 APIs.

Comment: using this extension and it's great

Answer (score 5):

Found an awesome tool that achieves the printing results that I asked for:
http://plessl.github.com/wkpdf/

Here's a quote from its website:
"*If you want to render a website with all the graphical icing to exactly match the view in a browser, you can explicitly force the use of the CSS screen stylesheet and enable the printing of background images as in the following example ...*"

So I ran:

```
wkpdf --source https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md
      --stylesheet-media screen
      --print-background yes
      --output printIt.pdf
```

and it was magical!

Comment: Cons: it runs only on OS X, it prints useless header and footer (does it? I can't try this tool because I'm on Linux)

Comment: And due to changes in OS X by Apple, wkpdf is no longer being maintained by the author.

Comment: The link is no longer valid. After a little bit of googling I think this link should be the correct one: https://github.com/plessl/wkpdf

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the [github-wiki-print](https://github.com/potomak/github-wiki-print) browser extension to print GitHub wiki pages.

I think you might edit its [manifest.json](https://github.com/potomak/github-wiki-print/blob/master/source/chrome/manifest.json#L12) file to print any markdown file on GitHub repos.

Answer (score 2):

clone the repo

```
gem install bluecloth
```

- render the markdown files into html
- open file on your filesystem in
  your browser
- print from your browser

http://deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth

you can find examples of the api here: http://deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth/browser/spec/bluecloth_spec.rb

Comment: `File.open("/path/to/output.html", 'w') {|f| f.write(BlueCloth.new(File.read("/path/to/input.md")).to_html()) }` got me an HTML page to look at but none of the formatting or coloring from GitHub is present. That is the key part in printing out a pretty version that I see on my browser, is BlueCloth an appropriate tool for that? How so?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend taking a picture with http://awesomescreenshot.com/, then cropping the image and printing (I just did this and it worked for me :).

Comment: Its not yet supported on my browser, I'll be sure to test the validity of this solution when it becomes available and vote it up if it actually works.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Hack:**

I've been opening the markdown file in something like [Marked](http://marked2app.com) or the online tool [Dillinger](http://dillinger.io) and then print from there. Some of these tools allow you to set the formatting to Github or other styles.

**A better way:**

Since I first wrote the above answer I found a better way:

I've discovered a better way than what I said earlier.

1. [Git clone your wiki](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-and-editing-wiki-pages-locally/) to a local directory
2. Use gitbook & Calibre's ebook-convert to generate the PDF as per the instructions in https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook

   - On the Mac, you have to symlink the ebook-convert from within the /Application/calibre.app directory to someplace suitable before running the gitbook pdf command, with a command like:

   ln -s /Applications/calibre.app/Contents/console.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert /usr/local/bin

Comment: Dillinger worked beautifully for me - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try grip.

```
pip install grip
grip markdown.md
```

Then it is hosted on a local port. You can then print or save to PDF through your native OS print dialog from your favourite browser.

See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/689056/how-can-i-convert-github-flavored-markdown-to-a-pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Super easy way that require nothing more than Chrome:

You can spoof the user-agent, telling you are a mobile device, to get a nice printable version.

The way I do it - there are plenty of ways - I use Chrome the Chrome devTools "Emulation" feature to emulate an Android device, e.g. a Samsung Note 3, then in the screen sub-section I remove "Emulate screen", to get full resolution, then I print.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is just download the markdown from GitHub or Bit Bucket and open it with eclipse. You will get the preview tab in the editor pane. From file menu select print. Simple way, however I am taking liberty to assume you already have eclipse installed usually most of developers have it.

BR

Answer (score 1):

I use this page http://www.markdownprint.com, really simple to use and produces markdown using the github style (which looks really good). Highly recommend!

Answer (score 1):

Simply convert **MD file into PDF**

You may download your .md file and upload it [here](https://www.markdowntopdf.com/) to convert it into a pdf file. Which you can easily print.

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/github/markup

You don't mention a language preference, but this is the Ruby library GitHub itself uses to render the markup files. It has the advantage of supporting the various [markups](http://github.com/github/markup/blob/master/README.md) GitHub supports (textile, rdoc etc). Rendering .markdown files has a dependency on the redcarpet markdown parser:

http://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet

Answer (score 0):

If you have an [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com/) account, navigate to the README.md file, save the link to Instapaper, then open the "text" option in Instapaper on that link. Most of the "clutter" is removed and the page prints well.

Answer (score 0):

I used [MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com/) and printed the HTML to a PDF writer. If you have Pro you can export to PDF directly.

Answer (score 0):

Works for Chromium browsers and "current" GitHub html page structure

1. Create a bookmark
2. In the Address field enter :

```js
javascript:var content = document.querySelector('.repository-content'); 
var toc = document.querySelector('#wiki-rightbar');
toc.innerHTML = '';
var wb = document.querySelector('.has-rightbar .wiki-body');
wb.style.marginRight = '0px';
var body = document.querySelector('body'); 
body.innerHTML = ''; 
body.appendChild(content);
window.print();
```

Selects the Wiki text, removes and formats the table of content, replaces the body content and calls the printer.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox it is super easy.

1. Select the portion to be printed, by simply dragging mouse from begin to end of the area to be printed.
2. Go to the print menu File -> Print (Ctrl-P will also work)
3. Click 'Selection' instead of Original under the 'Format' option of the print menu
4. Hit Print. The preview should also show what is going to be printed.