# How could I print source files from Github in .pdf, with syntaxic highlighting?

Tags: python, pdf, github, printing, export

I know people already asked [how to print Markdown files.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998337/how-to-print-from-github)

My question is different.

I'm learning Python ([The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org)), and in ex37 I need to print out some Python codes so I can read them on paper and read them on dead tree, while taking note with a pen and such.

I've been searching Google and S.O and haven't found how to **export a .py file, with syntaxic highlighting, into a .pdf file** so I may print it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://python.net/~gherman/py2pdf.html

Comment: Thank you. I want to flag your answer as the one that helped me, but I can't find how, maybe I don't have enough reputation yet to do that?

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`py2pdf` should do what you need: http://python.net/~gherman/py2pdf.html