# Print markdown file from GitHub

Tags: github, markdown, pretty-print

I wanted to share a simple way to pretty print markdown (*.md) files from GitHub.

I found a lot of interesting approaches, mainly in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998337/how-to-print-from-github). But none of them were updated and working, or what I was looking for (a *simple and comfortable way to pretty print*). Based on a couple of answers, I managed to make a solution myself that works.

Any other solutions are welcome as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I based my answer in [Boris Terzic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1996/boris-terzic)'s awesome answer, so I also made a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:document.querySelector('.markdown-body').setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 100; background-color: white; border:0');document.querySelector('body').appendChild(document.querySelector('.markdown-body'));window.print()
```

As [Boris Terzic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1996/boris-terzic) also explained, you should add the contents of the bookmarklet (copy-paste the code above) as a bookmark. Basically, *Add new bookmark*, give it an appropriate name, and copy-paste the code above as the URL.
Then, to use it, you have to:

1. Open the Git webpage of the *.md file you want to print.
2. Click on the bookmark you created; it will reformat the page, so it can print it afterwards.

Try with [an example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/README.md)!

Comment: This is a great idea. I tried it today, about 4 years later!   
Perhaps with newer versions of browsers, there's a bit of a problem.   
I tried it with Google chrome 117.0.5938.92 It works well when I try to print your example page to pdf or printer in landscape mode.   
However, in portrait mode, there are some overlapping texts. Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so I created a chrome extension that does exactly this: [GitHub Markdown Printer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-markdown-printer/fehpdlpmcegfpbkgcnaleindodeegapk). It's a **one-click** solution for printing markdown files **exactly** how they appear on GitHub.

It's [open source](https://github.com/jerry1100/github-markdown-printer) too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Apple device using Safari you can simply activate the reader view.
I think that this functionality is supported from other browsers like Firefox and Chrome as well.

[image]